# Add iteration counter to dict/list comprehension python

Tags: python

I want to add an iteration counter to my list comprehension so that each key will have its own number based on which iteration we are on

currently:

```
itemdict = {item.name: [item.size, item.price] for item in items}
```

Which gives: `{ItemNameExample: ['size=15', 'price=100']}`

I want to do something like:

```
counter = 0
itemdict = {str(counter+=1) +'. '+ item.name: [item.size, item.price] for item in items}
```

Which would give me sometime like:
`{1. ItemNameExample: ['size=15', 'price=100']}`

But the above code I tried always gives a `1` rather than adding to the count based on iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
itemdict = {str(i) + '. ' + item.name: [item.size, item.price]
            for i, item in enumerate(items, 1)}
```

Comment: If you use `enumerate(items, 1)` you can replace the `str(i+1)` with just `str(i)`. The second argument to `enumerate` dictates what integer the sequence starts at.